# Can I use non-fine-tuned BERT model from TF HUB to serve it with TF serving?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, bert-language-model

I'm a new to `TF serving` and currently I have such kind of problem. I run server part using [bert_en_uncased](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1) from `TF HUB`, but I don't understand how to implement client side correctly. I faced with a couple of articles but each of them assumes that I have a ready-made fine-tuned model with pre-assigned handlers for requests. Can anyone share some tutors or maybe API references to facilitate my task?

Some of articles I have read:

- [Deploy a Servable Question Answering Model Using TensorFlow Serving](https://medium.com/@joyceye04/deploy-a-servable-bert-qa-model-using-tensorflow-serving-d848f9797d9)
- [3 Ways to Optimize and Export BERT Model for Online Serving](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-optimize-and-export-bert-model-for-online-serving-8f49d774a501)
- [Use BERT fine-tuned model for Tensorflow serving (GitHub issue)](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/146)

PS. I'm not trying to create QA model or something like that, I just need BERT embeddings from this particular model.

Answer (score 1):

UPD: a've already solved this problem. The main thing was, `TF.HUB` model don't have any spec list or something like that, only some documentation of how you can use it with `tf.hub`. If you faced with similar problem do I recommend to do the following things:
1) Install/compile from source `SavedModelCli`, it's TensorFlow's tool to, let's say, unpack saved models and get it's specs;
2) Find some guides on `TF Serving`, just change some code pieces, nearly every implementation is the same;
3) Probably you might (and you WILL, believe me) face with deprecation warnings. Don't try to look for documentation, solution was here :)
Good luck on serving your models!